# GWT DateField - 'ExceptionInInitializerError'

Tags: gwt, gwt-ext

I am new to GWT. I am trying to develop a GWT application. In my project I am using a 'DateField' as follows,

`DateField  dob = new DateField("Birthday", "d/m/y");`


When I am trying to run in hosted mode, I am getting the error
*java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null*


I am using Google plugin for Eclipse 3.5 (Version - 1.1.1.v200909221731),
 Google Web Toolkit SDK 1.7.1( Version -1.7.1.v200909221731),
 ext-2.0.2

Please guide me on this.
Any pointers are welcome.

Thanks,

SD

Comment: If you could provide some more info: 1) Have you used the Google plugin to create your app? (if so, are you sure you set up GXT properly? http://www.extjs.com/helpcenter/index.jsp has a Getting started section) 2) Post the whole (or at least a bigger portion) of the stack trace

Comment: Yes, I used Google plugin to create my app. I had updated the '.gwt.xml' file with below lines,
 <inherits name='com.gwtext.GwtExt' />
<stylesheet src="js/ext/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
  <script src="js/ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js" />
  <script src="js/ext/ext-all.js" />

Also, I added the gwt-ext jar to lib and classpath.
Am I missing any configuration now ?

Comment: Stack trace,<br>
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
 at todos.client.Todos.printToDosOfSelectedProject(Todos.java:325)
 at todos.client.Todos.access$2(Todos.java:270)
..................
at com.google.gwt.dev.HostedMode.main(HostedMode.java:232)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): $wnd.Ext has no properties
 fileName: jar:file:/home/sindhu/eclipsews/todos/war/WEB-INF/lib/gwtext.jar!/com/gwtext/client/widgets/Component.java
 lineNumber: 118

Comment: Aaaand what's on Todos.java:325? DateField dob = new DateField("Birthday", "d/m/y");? Some source code would be nice ;)